# HTTPmodule or similar for SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, http-module

Can we build a httpmodule or something similar for SharePoint online?

My requirement is to redirect user to custom page when they click on any document link in SharePoint document library or search results.

With classic UI I can achieve this via DOM manipulation but it is not possible with modern UI?

Any suggestion from spfx?

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot create http module. You need to crate your own search template this way you can manipulate the target url. For the library you check can you achieve what you need with the field formatter.